# Input suggest - проблемы с кодировкой

Tags: ajax, кодировка

Добрый день!

Потребовалось сделать небольшой `suggest` для формы поиска.
Нашел крайне удобную [вариацию](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_ajax_livesearch.asp), как раз нужно было что бы еще и ссылки можно было вешать.
Но оно не работает для кириллицы.

Если заставить `XML` быть в `ср-1251`, то кириллические выражения крутит, но выдает в ответе кракозябры.
Подскажите, где в *livesearch.php* вставить декодер из `ср-1251` в `unicode`, что бы получать результат в правильной кодировке.

Answer (score 0):

В результате с кодировкой я разобрался.
Добавил:

```
$hint = mb_convert_encoding($hint, "CP-1251", "UTF-8");
```

Перед проверкой на пустоту ответа.
Так же немного изменил скрипт, добавив в xml файл поле `<alias> </alias>`
В которое как раз записываю все возможные вариации написания, на различных языках, с ошибками и прочим, и по которому осуществляю проверку.

Но тут вот какой вопрос появился - как бы ограничить кол-во выводимых записей?